# How to move buttons to fit on bottom of container

Tags: css, html

I am building a website using html5 and css.

How do I move these buttons so they fit on the bottom of the container?

[image]

Use the image below as a reference.

[image]

CSS for buttons :

```
.button_buy{
height: 38px;
background: #35424a;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
border: #e8491d 1px solid;
border-top: #e8491d 2px solid;
border-bottom: #e8491d 2px solid;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: It would useful to see your markup as well.  Also, even with the images I am not quite sure what you are asking, nor what "How do I move these buttons so they fit on the bottom of the container?".  I might be helpful to include two pictures-- one showing the current result, one showing the desired result.

Comment: make your `button_buy` class `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` that will do in docking button bottom.

Comment: @noob please add html code also

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent container to `position:relative` and the set the button/buttonContainer to `position:absolute`. This will always position this element with respect to the container.

**ELSE**

You can use the `display:flex` to achieve the same results.

Refer snippet for both methods.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button_container {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.button_buy {
  height: 38px;
  background: #35424a;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: #e8491d 1px solid;
  border-top: #e8491d 2px solid;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 2px solid;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.flex_container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex_child {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button_container">
    <button class="button_buy">Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_child">
    <button class="button_buy">Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```